# My subscriber has the "edit comment" capability but can't edit comment

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

When i use the wp_get_current_user function to display all informations about my user (subscriber), it shows that i can edit comment :

[image]

I tried to display an edit comment button next to each comment that belongs to my user. However, in the edit_comment_link func there is this condition that checks if the user can edit comment :

[image]

And it turns out that this condition doesn't pass. I don't get how this could be true on one side and false on the other side...

I disable all my plugins and the problem is still here so i don't think it comes from this... i can't find any answer helpful, nothing works so far...

Does anyone have any idea? :(

Comment: So you have a user that is set as a 'Subscriber'. This 'Subscriber' cannot edit their OWN comments?

Comment: That's right, they can't edit their own comments

Comment: I believe the limitation here is that the `comment` capability is made possible via the `Comments` section in the back-end of WordPress. It would be possible to enable editing, however it would be in the form of the back-end. Is that something you were after, or only editing via the front-end?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use an external / 3rd party plugin such as https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-comment-editing/

Comment: I already tried this plugin but it doesn't change anything :/ I would prefer to edit comment in the front but editing in the back could be okay i guess

Comment: For the plugin to work, I found that you are still required to have permissions to edit posts. What might be a good idea is to set the default user to `Author` and add code to remove the WP Admin Bar (at the top of the page) and remove page access to the backend. That way users have access to edit their comments without the other abilities.